# After Effects: Shortcut for showing all transforming properties of a layer

Tags: after-effects, short

just wondering if there is a shortcut in after effects to reveal all transforming properties (scale, position, opacity, etc.) of a selected layer at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some shortcuts depend on the **language** and your **keyboard layout**.

For a german layout it's: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ü</kbd>.

---

However **concatenating** the shortcuts always works.

For *Scale*, *Position* and *Opacity* press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

There's 3 [options](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html):

<kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> for *Toggle expansion of selected layers to show all properties*

<kbd>UU</kbd> for *Show only modified properties*

<kbd>U</kbd> for *Show only properties with keyframes or expressions*

Comment: Mhh. `Ctrl +` does not work here... Also I can't find it in the menu.

Comment: It's Ctrl + grave (key above Tab / below Esc).